# SVN family of products versioning

Tags: svn

We are building a family of products. Each of the product, within the family is built on common "infrastructure" component. So we have various application teams, which are working on Product A, Product B, and infrastructure component within the family f.

Typically, product A, B.. X and infrastructure would have their own release cycles, independent of each other. So our versioning strategy is 2 fold. Products/infrastructure are versioned independently and then a deployed family is versioned.

Not all the products would be created at the same time. Hence,few example deployments are:-

Family1.0 [infrastructure-1.0, product A-1.0]

Family1.0.1 [infrastructure-1.0, product A-1.1]

Family1.2 [infrastructure-1.1, product A-2.0]

Family2.0 [infrastructure-1.2, product A-2.0, product B-1.0]

Hence, i have created a SVN directory structure such as

```
family
    /tags
/product A
    /tags
    /trunk
/product B
    /tags
    /trunk
/infrastructure
    /tags
    /trunk
```

My Question is how can i make the following possible

```
/family
    /tags
        /tag1.0 <-- should refer to infrastructure tag 1.0 and product A tag1.0
/product A
    /tags
        /tag1.0
/infrastructure
    /tags
        /tag1.0
```

Hence, family tag1.0 should refer to product A tag 1.0 and infrastructure tag1.0.

Comment: Probably your question has nothing to do with svn itself, but with deployment and dependency management software

Comment: we are using svn to manage dependency and svn to manage a deployment snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use svn:externals properety ([here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)) but instead of linking to someone else repository you specify your repository.

So product A would have an external set to http://myrepourl.com/infrastructure/tags/tag1.0

And product be could then have an external set to http://myrepourl.com/infrastructure/tags/tag1.1.

This is the only way I could think to accomplish the multiple dependencies unless it was somehow in your configuration files (or a versioned script that would check out the correct infrastructure).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a snapshot of all the projects then you branch the root into the tags folder

you go from:

```
/tags
/trunk
    /family           
    /product_A
    /product_B
    /infrastructure
```

to

```
/tags
    /tag1.0               ; Snapshot of trunk with all the projects
        /family           
        /product_A
        /product_B
        /infrastructure
/trunk
    /family           
    /product_A
    /product_B
    /infrastructure
```